# Enlarged part of the chart

Tags: pgfplots

How can I take out an enlarged part of the chart?

I've got an example. On my chart I need to scale red box.

There is a code for the chart:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin = 0, ymax = 75,title ={U=f(I)} ,xlabel = {$I$}, ylabel = {$U$},]
\addplot table {
    x     y
    225   45
    83   50
    38   54.3
    18   57.2
    8.8   59
    4.8   60.3
    1.95   68.4
    0.95   69.15
    0.5   69.4
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thanks

[image: example]
[image: My chat]
[image: dragged chart]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `spy` for that.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} 
\usetikzlibrary{spy} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines={magnification=pi, size=3cm, connect spies}]
\begin{axis}[xmin = 0, ymax = 75,title ={U=f(I)} ,xlabel = {$I$}, ylabel = {$U$},]
\addplot table {
    x     y
    225   45
    83   50
    38   54.3
    18   57.2
    8.8   59
    4.8   60.3
    1.95   68.4
    0.95   69.15
    0.5   69.4
};
\path (0.5,69.4) coordinate (p);
\end{axis}
\spy [red] on (p)
in node [above left] at ([xshift=-1.1cm]current axis.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[name=large axis,xmin = 0, ymax = 75,title ={$U=f(I)$} ,xlabel = {$I$}, ylabel = {$U$},]
\addplot table {
    x     y
    225   45
    83   50
    38   54.3
    18   57.2
    8.8   59
    4.8   60.3
    1.95   68.4
    0.95   69.15
    0.5   69.4
};
\path (0.5,69.4) coordinate (ptl) (4.8,60.3) coordinate (pbr);
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[anchor=north east,at={(large axis.north west)},xshift=-1.3cm,
    xmin = 0, ymax = 75,title ={$U=f(I)$} ,xlabel = {$I$}, ylabel = {$U$},
    width=5cm]
\addplot    table {
    x     y
    4.8   60.3
    1.95   68.4
    0.95   69.15
    0.5   69.4
};
\end{axis}
\draw[red] (ptl) rectangle (pbr) coordinate[midway](aux)
(aux-|ptl) -- (current axis.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but it just enlarged it. Is it possible to scale chart in dragged red box? I've add what I need to see there. Thanks

Comment: @RuslanNevretdinov For that I'd just do a separate plot in which one only plots these points.

Comment: @RuslanNevretdinov I added something of that sort.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: But I've got one more question. How can I make the red line from the left side, not from the right (not to cross the box)? Thanks!!

Comment: @RuslanNevretdinov Fixed. My bad.

Comment: Thank you so much